# resize several sections together in qtableview header

Tags: qt, qtableview

After I set `QHeaderView::setResizeMode(QHeaderView::Interactive)`, how could I make several header sections resize together. For example, when I decrease the size of one section (drag its right border to left), I hope all its left sections decrease their sizes also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `void QHeaderView::sectionResized ( int logicalIndex, int oldSize, int newSize )` signal. This signal is emitted when a section is resized. The section's logical number is specified by `logicalIndex`, the old size by `oldSize`, and the new size by `newSize`.

So it can be done simply by connecting this signal to a slot to update the previous header sizes :

```
connect(ui->tableView->horizontalHeader(),SIGNAL(sectionResized(int,int,int)),this,SLOT(updateSizes(int,int,int)));
```

`updateSizes` slot is like :

```
void updateSizes(int logicalIndex, int oldSize, int newSize )
{

    for(int i=0; i<logicalIndex; i++)
         ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->resizeSection(i, newSize);
}
```